# HTML Caption not scaling correctly

Tags: html

I have got a headline (`<h1>`) with a long text. Since the text does not fit into one line, the browser breaks the line. However, the height of the headline does not scale, i.e., a headline without a linebreak has the same height than one with a linebreak. I am using a background image which should always be behind all the text of the headline. But since the height does not scale, the headline with the implicit linebreak looks awkward: The background is only behind the first line, the second line has no background at all. Why doesn't the headline scale and how can I make it scale?

Comment: Can you add a jsfiddle please

Comment: We can't help you without seeing your markup and CSS. If you can edit your question to show the relevant parts of that, please flag it for moderator review to be re-opened.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default the background scale here is a simple example

```
<html>
<style>
    h1 { width: 5em; background-color: #EFA; }
</style>
<body>
<h1>A very long title which cannot enter into only one line!</h1>
</body>
</html>
```

Now, to help you:

- you might didn't set the `h1 {background-repeat: y-repeat;}` correctly in the CSS.
  Or
- you might had forced the h1 height: `h1 { height: 20px; }` which is wrong if you want to be able to manage different height.

Comment: So what was the part of the accepted answer that solved the problem?

Answer (score 1):

It does scale: http://jsfiddle.net/charlescarver/uUpqL/

My guess is that you're either setting a height to your `<h1>` tag, or your background image isn't repeating with the stretch.

Answer (score 0):

Well, assuming you want the `h1` to have only one line:

```
h1 {
    white-space: nowrap;
}
```

If you want the `h1` to have only one line *and* be contained within a given width:

```
h1 {
    width: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
    white-space: nowrap;
}
```